# Python super class __init__()?

Tags: python

```
class Fetcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.opener = urllib.opener()
    def query(self, something):
        self.opener.open(something)

class Person (Fetcher):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         super().function()
    def fetch(self):
        super().query()
```

How can I rewrite Fetcher query method to skip Fetcher.**init** for every Person to obtain self.opener? Or even my pattern is wrong? If that is Ok, what about memory?

Comment: Are you asking how you can make sure a constructor isn't called?

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? How are these classes intended to be used?

Comment: Do you want to create one opener to share across all instances of Fetcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would naturally call the `__init__` of the superclass while initialising the subclass. However, you can avoid defining a new opener object per instance by making it a class attribute of the superclass:

```
class Fetcher:
    opener = urllib.opener()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def query(self, something):
        self.opener.open(something)

class Person (Fetcher):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().function()

    def fetch(self):
        super().query()
```